# DOS concatenated commands order of precedence

Tags: batch-file, dos

What is wrong with the code below, that is intended to only report something is done if it returns cleanly:

```
echo Other operations here & (echo Trying to launching Firefox & "%ProgramFiles(x64)%"\Mozilla\Firefox\Firefox.exe && echo Firefox has closed successfully) & echo More operations that should be done regardless here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, this syntax works, there was other issues with the surrounding code that I didn't realise. Don't suppose anyone knows of a better way to debug DOS "scripting", it's almost as bad as VBS error messages!

Comment: A "better" way? Allowing that "better" is a rather subjective measure; unless putting everything on a single line makes the code more readable I think splitting your code into separate lines would be "better". Anything that `&&` and `||` react to correctly uses uses an exit code that can be accessed via the `%errorlevel%` variable. Remember, programming is not Golf, and though the shortest code may be the more efficient code, efficient code is worthless if you (or whoever else is maintaining it) can't understand it later so it can be adapted to changing needs.

Comment: Hi @JamesK - Agree, better is subjective, but my difficulties with debugging is not limited to times when I decide to concatenate commands on one line. Thanks for pointing out about the errorlevels, should have thought of that myself :( As for your point about single line commands, yes it is not easier to maintain, nor easy for others to understand, but the intention for this project is that only I will be maintining it, so these perfectly valid points *should* outweight the pros, imo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your syntax is correct, but your expectations are wrong.

You are launching a Windowed application - your command will not wait for Firefox to close before it carries on. Your code is probably properly reporting that Firefox was started. Only if Firefox fails to ***start*** (perhaps it doesn't exist on the machine), only then will your conditional code be bypassed.

Normally, if you want to launch a Windowed application and wait for it to finish (close) before continuing, then you would use START /WAIT.

```
echo previous command & (start /wait "" yourApp.exe && echo successful closure) & echo additional commmands
```

However, I'm not sure that will work with a browser like Firefox. Many browsers consist of multiple executables. The launching executable may launch auxiliary procsses and then shut down. Your command would happily report that the launching exe returned with success, even though the browser would still be running. Again, I'm not sure if Firefox behaves like this. But if it does, then the problem becomes much more difficult. You would have to run a process that polls to see if Firefox is still active.